# Google Auth does not work in template asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, owin

So I have VS 2013 update 4 and I created ASP.NET MVC application from template and configured Google authentication by using UseGoogleAuthentication method and passing client ID and secret. But for some reason once I click 'Accept' button google page I'm redirected to the page I expect but there is an error 500 in the browser console and nothing on the page itself.

I read a lot of articles and enabled all required APIs in Google Developer console. But nothing seems to work for me.

Also I have another custom authentication middleware that worked just fine before and stopped working once I enabled Google. I use nuget package version 3.0.1.

If I disable my custom auth middleware Google still does not work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's why should probably stay with default values. So default redirect URL is /signin-google built-in to Google middleware. And because my URL is /Account/ExternalLoginCallback I thought it was a good idea to set it when configuring GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.

Once removed CallbackPath = new PathString("Account/ExternalLoginCallback") from configuration it just worked.